# Using the regular expression [\[\];] in flex

Tags: regex, lexical-analysis

If I have the following in my flex file, what does it do?

```
[\\[\\];]     { return yytext[0]; }
```

Comment: I do not know flex, but in most regex engines, if the first character after [ is ] then it's considered part of the character class. So this regex can probably be rewritten as: [][;]

Comment: @Peter: in most flavors the `[` would still have to be escaped: `[]\[;]` (or `[]\\[;]` in a context that requires backslashes to be escaped).  To me, that looks even more confusing; better just to escape them both.

Comment: @Alan - Maybe, I can only test it here for .Net regexes and GVIM. Which both do not require `[` to be escaped. I can't imagine why it needs to be since in a character class it has no special meaning

Comment: Many regex flavors support POSIX-style bracket expressions ( http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html ); some support set subtraction (`[[a-z]-[aeiou]]`) or intersection (`[[a-z]&&[^aeiou]]`).  You can often get away with not escaping the `[` anyway, but you'll never go wrong by escaping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matches a token consisting of one of the characters `[`, `]` or `;`. @AAT is is right in his explanation, though terminology wise "character class" is more common than "character range".

`return yytext[0];` returns the first character of the matched token. Since the regexp here matches only single character tokens, it returns the matched token itself as a character.

Answer (score 2):

If it was in Perl, it would match any of '[', ']', or ';' -- I imagine it's the same in flex.
The outer "[...]" defines a character range, i.e. matches any one of the specified characters: the backslashes escape the inner "[]" so that they just mean literal brackets.

Answer (score 0):

if it finds any of the follwing []; it returns yytext[0]

Comment: You sure? In most regex flavors I know, characters inside `[` and `]` are treated as a character class: it matches just a single character defined in them.

Comment: .. perhaps Flex handles it differently.